# Type for object in React/Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What is the type for a object in React/Typescript for example:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState<any>({});
```

if I need to define it as an object what type would I put in, instead of `<any>`

Comment: If you know that it is an object but you don't know the keys and values go with `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>`. If you know that keys are strings, use `Record<string, unknown>`

Comment: Well what _are_ you planning to put it that object? The more information you give the compiler, the more helpful it can be.

Answer (score 3):

```
interface MyObject {
  [k: string]: any;
}

const [value, setValue] = React.useState<MyObject>({});
```

[k: string]: any; means that property must be a string, and it's value are any.